# Advice on background processing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

In a project I’ve recently taken over, there is a call to a function which does some calculations; this is called in a row, several times (between 1 and 10 times usually).

```
While dr.read  ‘depending on a db call, loop 1 or more times
 Dim calc As New CalcClass
 Dim newDoStuff As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoStuff))
 newDoStuff.Start(calc)
End while

Private Sub DoStuff(ByVal calc As Object)
‘do something that takes between 5-10 seconds
End sub
```

In order to speed this up, i am trying to add asynchronous processing (see above example), this works in my code, all tasks are done at the same time, but what I don’t understand is how to then wait for all these threads to finish (there is no set amount of threads, it can be between 1 and 10 depending on some other data) before finishing up with a final task that needs to run after all tasks are completed.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this – I’m looking for an easy way to basically say “O.k, all tasks are finished at this point, call another task”

Cliffs

- Several tasks need to run at the same time (between 1 and 10)
- Each task takes several seconds
- Code currently works - it does them all at the same time
- Once all tasks (between 1-10) are
  finished, fire off some other code (only when all tasks are finished) - *stuck on best method to do the following*

Comment: If you can, I'd rework this to use the Parrel task library. The method to wait on other threads is called `Join` though. Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx

Comment: I don't know of a way to wait a thread to finished without using callbacks.  I suggest not launching a thread for each task, perhaps combine them into multiple tasks, and report the status on each group.

Comment: @asawyer - While your advice is sound.  The TPL is not ready for prime time.  It will be contained with .NET Framework 4.5 from my understand.  He doesn't need to use TPL to use the Thread.Join method.  You have to be careful of Thread.Join you can easily cause yourself a Deadlock.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I actually meant pLinq, not sure how I got them mixed up! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your thread in an List

```
Dim threads As new List(Of System.Threading.Thread)

While dr.read  ‘depending on a db call, loop 1 or more times
    Dim calc As New CalcClass
    Dim newDoStuff As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoStuff))
    threads.Add(newDoStuff)
    newDoStuff.Start(calc) 
End while
```

finally join all your threads

```
For Each thread In threads Do
    thread.Join()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put all of your new threads into a list, then iterate over that list and call [.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) on each one.  The join method blocks the current thread until the thread you are Joining completes:

Apologies if there are any syntactic errors in the following code- I don't have VB handy and my memory of the syntax is pretty rusty:

```
Dim threadList as New List(Of Thread)
While dr.read  ‘depending on a db call, loop 1 or more times
 Dim calc As New CalcClass
 Dim newDoStuff As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf DoStuff))
 newDoStuff.Start(calc)
 threadList.Add(newDoStuff)
End while
For Each t as Thread in ThreadList
    t.Join
End For
```

With that said, I'd strongly encourage you to look into using the classes in the [System.Threading.Tasks namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608.aspx), as that provides a much better paradigm than starting and managing your own threads.